# Why does my CSV output contain each column twice?

Tags: php, csv

I have the following:

```
$name = 'registrations.csv';
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. $name);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Expires: 0");
$outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");
$results = mysql_query("select * from registrations");
while( $result = mysql_fetch_array($results) )
{
  fputcsv($outstream, $result);
}
fclose($outstream);
```

This works great, except it gives two of every column.  For example, I have a given_name column and a surname column in the table.  The resulting csv file shows each column twice.  Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `mysql_fetch_array()` to `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. `mysql_fetch_array()` fetches both a numeric and associative array of the database results.

```
while( $result = mysql_fetch_assoc$results) )
{
  fputcsv($outstream, $result);
}
```