# removing data from sql query in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

sorry if my title is not good.

my problem is with data in array from sql query.

my sql query:

```
$num = mysql_query("SELECT `id_product_attribute`,`id_product`,`reference` FROM `ps_product_attribute`")
```

i retreive data with this code:

```
$nameArray = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($num)) {
    $nameArray[] = $row;   
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($nameArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

the output looks like this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
            [id_product_attribute] => 45
            [1] => 10640
            [id_product] => 10640
            [2] => 1041-0567041700116
            [reference] => 1041-0567041700116
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 46
            [id_product_attribute] => 46
            [1] => 10640
            [id_product] => 10640
            [2] => 1041-0567041700318
            [reference] => 1041-0567041700318
        ) etc.
```

but i want the output like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45
            [1] => 10640
            [2] => 1041-0567041700116
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 46
            [1] => 10640
            [2] => 1041-0567041700318
        ) etc.
```

what do i need to change in my code to achive this?

if i use `fetch_assoc` then i'll get the oposite result.

Comment: Please,  RTFM. http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my CSV output contain each column twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230470/why-does-my-csv-output-contain-each-column-twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the type of result, otherwise you'll get both:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    ...
}
```

Also, you should really switch to another adapter (PDO, mysqli, etc.).

Comment: thank you very much. it worked! yes, i know that mysql is deprecated and i will change this later, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_array` accepts an optional second parameter.

Like this:

```
array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )
```

Pass the constant `MYSQL_NUM` to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Specific function aside, you *really* should be switching to `mysqli_` classes & function, since all the `mysql_` functions are set to be removed at some point in the future. There are other advantages to them, but not so much if you're just using them as a direct replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$nameArray = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($num, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $nameArray[] = $row;   
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($nameArray);
echo '</pre>';
```